# How to deserialize Kotlin delegates in GSON

Tags: javafx, gson, kotlin

I have this class:

```
class Project {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty("foobar")
    val name by nameProperty
}
```

I use [Fx-GSON](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/fx-gson) library to serialize JavaFx Properties.

When I serialize it to JSON I get this:

```
{
    "nameProperty": "foobar",
    "name$delegate": "foobar"
}
```

But when I deserialize it back to the object of type `Project` the `name` and `nameProperty` are **2 different objects**.

How to make `name` property delegate to the new `nameProperty`?

Answer (score 1):

You could build something based on GSON's [`ExclusionStrategy`](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html) to exclude delegate fields from serialization. Either by checking for the `$delegate` field suffix or by using Kotlin's reflection.